# How can i see which reaction emoji has been used the most?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to see which emoji has been used to react with the most on posts in a discord server that i'm a member of

Does anyone know how i can do this?

My knowledge of discord programming and use of bots is almost non existent

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) the `fetchMessages`fetch all Messages in a given channel.

The problem is the following part

> The returned Collection does not contain reaction users of the messages if they were not cached. Those need to be fetched separately in such a case.

So you will get a [`collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of message but without reaction. You'll need to fetch the messages one by one with [`fetchMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) (which is redundant because you already have the messages in the returned collection, but I don't see a better solutions after reading the doc).

Then once you have fetched a message, you'll need to get it [reactions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions).

Read the `fetchMessages` options (limit for example).

It could be long.